# How can I have two analogue inputs, control two PWM outputs on PIC16f?

Tags: pic, pwm

I'm looking to have dual PWM out from a PIC16f1619. This is part of a power supply project that has pots for limiting voltage and current. I'm simulating control of the regulator with just two LEDs at the moment.

In debug mode (on Microchip Curiosity board) the Analog_AN0 never seems to run, yet both RC6 and RC7 output dependent on PORTA0 only (not seperately controlled).

I can't have set the PWM and ADC correctly but I am unsure why.

Any help would be appreciated as I am pulling my hair out over what I am sure is a simple problem.

```
#define _XTAL_FREQ 16000000 //16mhz
#include <xc.h>

#define RS RC0
#define EN RC1
#define D4 RC2
#define D5 RC3
#define D6 RC4
#define D7 RC5


void Analog_AN0(void)
{
    PWM3CON = 0b10000000;//Enable the PWM3 H/W
    RC6PPS = 0b00001110; //Sets RC6 to output PWM3
    ADCON0 = 0b00000001; //pin RAO is connected to AN0. ADC ON
    ADCON1bits.ADCS = 0; //Conversion clk of fosc/2 (time required to convert each bit)
    ADCON1bits.ADPREF = 1; //Vref is VDD 3.3V
    ADCON1bits.ADFM = 0; // will right-justify the result and store the 10bit value  in the16bit register ADRES
    ADCON2 = 0;
    PWM3DCL = ADRESL;
    PWM3DCH = ADRESH;
}
void Analog_AN1(void)
{
    PWM4CON = 0b10000000; //Enable PWM4 H/W
    RC7PPS = 0b00001111; //Sets RC7 to output PWM4
    ADCON0 = 0b00000011; //pin RA1 is connected to AN1. ADC ON
    ADCON1bits.ADCS = 0; //Conversion clk of fosc/2 (time required to convert each bit)
    ADCON1bits.ADPREF = 1; //Vref is VDD 3.3V
    ADCON1bits.ADFM = 0; // will right-justify the result and store the 10bit value  in the16bit register ADRES
    ADCON2 = 0;
    PWM4DCL = ADRESL;
    PWM4DCH = ADRESH;
}
void main (void)
{
    OSCCON = 0b01011000;//sets clck to 1mhz
    ANSELC = 0x00; //Sets PortC as digital
    TRISC = 0x00;
    ANSELA = 0b11111100; //all pins on A are digital except 0 and1
    TRISA = 0b00000011; //all pins on A are output except 0 and 1
    INTCONbits.GIE = 0; //No interrupts
    CCPTMRSbits.P3TSEL0 = 0; //Associates TMR2 with PWM3
    CCPTMRSbits.P4TSEL0 = 0; //Associates TMR4 with PWM4
    //Set up Timer 2
    T2CON = 0b01110000; //TMR2 OFF, prescaler 128, postscaler 1;
    T2CLKCON = 0x00; //fosc/4
    PR2 = 19; //10ms NEED TO RECALCULATE
    TMR2 = 0x00; //Starting condition
    PIR1bits.TMR2IF = 0; //Empties the flag to begin
    T2CONbits.T2ON = 1; //init. timer
    //Set up Timer 4
    T4CON = 0b01110000;//TMR2 off, pre 128, post 16
    T4CLKCON = 0x00; //fosc/4
    PR4 = 19; //10ms NEED TO RECALCULATE
    TMR4 = 0x00; //Starting condition
    PIR2bits.TMR4IF = 0; //Empties the flag to begin
    T4CONbits.T4ON = 1; //init. timer

    while (1)
    { 
        PIR1bits.ADIF=0;//makes sure that the flag is clear
        Analog_AN0();
        __delay_ms(10);
        Analog_AN1();
        // ADCON0bits.GO=1; //Conversion now starts




    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to be setting to GO/nDONE bit. You're just turning the ADC module on (bit 0 of ADCON0/2). Read the examples in the datasheet how do you do ADC conversion. You need to set the GO bit to '1' and then wait for the hardware to turn it back to '0' after the conversion is complete and ADRESL/ADRESH updated.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise that there was a difference in the enable bit and the on bit. Thank you very much!